# How to add tabs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ event: "mouseover" });        
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","#tab-4","Friends Discussions");
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","#tab-5","Announcements");
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","#tab-6","Contact");
    });
</script>

<div class="demo" align="center" >
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Recent Discussions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Most Popular Discussions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Most Viewed Discussions</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>111111111111</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>222222222222</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>333333333333333</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-4">
            <p>4444444444</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-5">
            <p>555555555</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-6">
            666666666
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tabs 4, 5 and 6 have got the same content as appears in tab 1, 2 and 3. Why does that happen?

Comment: Please put up a jsFiddle so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: Why all the down/close votes? It's not hard to understand the question, not does it not have merit?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/xJjfC/ and the same with Rory's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/xJjfC/1/

Comment: lol..that was the demo example jquery documentation gave..teh code isnt mine

Comment: The problem is you wrote $("#tabs").tabs("add","#tab-n"[...] instead of $("#tabs").tabs("add","#"tabs-n"[...] see my prev fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo in the tabs you're adding.  The `id` of the divs has to match the second parameter of each function.

Your divs look like this:

```
<div id="tabs-4">
```

But your code references:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("add","#tab-4","Friends Discussions");
                           ^
                           s is missing
```

Try this code instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/ugjLs/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs("add","#tabs-4","Friends Discussions");
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs("add","#tabs-5","Announcements");
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs("add","#tabs-6","Contact");
});
```

Comment: Same answer, 4 minutes earlier. What's a brother gotta do to get an accept around here ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's a typo in your code, you are adding `#tab-n`, yet in your code they have the Id `tabs-n`.

Try this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("add","#tabs-4","Friends Discussions");
$("#tabs").tabs("add","#tabs-5","Announcements");
$("#tabs").tabs("add","#tabs-6","Contact");
```